# In objective-c what if a property's backup ivar is declared explicitly?

Tags: objective-c, properties, reactive-cocoa, ivar

In ReactiveCococa 2.5, RACMulticastConnection has a **signal** property, which is a **RACSignal**, while in its implementation, it has a ivar **_signal**, which is a **RACSubject**. I just wondered if the signal's backup ivar is the _signal, how to explain it?

ok, it seems that my question isn't clear, I put some demo code here, hope someone can answer it.

the header file:

```
@interface RACMulticastConnection : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) RACSignal *signal;
...
@end
```

the impl file:

```
@interface RACMulticastConnection () {
    RACSubject *_signal;
    ...
}
...
```

One more thing, there is no @synthesize code in its implementation and as you all known, RACSubject is a subclass of RACSignal.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just wondered if the signal's backup ivar is the _signal

Maybe...

- If the implementation file has **no** `@synthesize signal` of any form then the property is auto-implementated (the standard approach) and the ivar `_signal` will be used as the backing variable. If there was no ivar `_signal` then one would be automatically created.

That leaves two, primarily historical, options:

- If there is an `@synthesize signal` then that will introduce an ivar `signal` to use as the backing variable, and the declared ivar `_signal` will not be associated in anyway to the property.
- Finally if there is an `@synthesize signal = _signal` then the ivar `_signal` will be used as the backing variable.

**Addendum: After comment/question edit**

Your edits to the question simply fix the above answer to the first bullet (the no `@synthesize` case).

Maybe you are concerned over the property having the type `RACSignal *` while the ivar has the type `RACSubject *`?

Remember the property is `readonly` so the only way to assign to it is using an assignment to `_signal` within the implementation, and the compiler will check that such an assignment has the type `RACSubject *` (or a subtype).

A client of the class reads the value using the property and is told the value is of type `RACSignal *`, and it is as `RACSubject` is a subclass of `RACSignal` so everything is type correct.

Using `RACSubject *` for the ivar is a way to improve checking within the implementation - i.e. the property returns an `RACSignal *` but the implementation knows that it will always return the subclass `RACSubject` so why not state that so the compiler will catch cases when it does not?

To demonstrate the compiler is checking try changing the type of `_signal`, say to `NSArray`, and you will get a compiler error stating that the type does not conform to the one required by the property.

HTH

Comment: @Josscii - see Addendum. HTH

Comment: ok, thanks for your explanation ! When I was first see this in this source code, I didn't use like this before, so I want to make sure it's correct and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly, to provide explicit name to ivar for property, just add

```
@synthesize propertyName = ivarName;
```

If you don't provide name, then compiler do it for you using template:

```
@synthesize propertyName = _propertyName;
```

I hope, I answered you question.